# Show all of my picture in cordova view

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I need to show all of the pictures that I took with a specific app (or in case it is not possible, show them all). It should work for Android and iOS so I decided to use Cordova.

Is there a plugin or a way to show all the pictures in a view (no I am not talking about an image picker from where I need to select one), I want to show them all into a view, with custom UI.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Given that Cordova uses HTML - you could create any custom view you want to with HTML and CSS. I guess this isn't much of an answer, but you really don't need anything "special" to display images (assuming you know the ones you want to show).

Comment: my question is more concerned on how I get images urls from cordova

Comment: Well most likely then you want to look at the FileSystem API.